# Align bottom if near bottom of screen othweise align top

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I've added a kebab menu to a project using alpine.js (not really relevant I don't think), and it works nicely, but I'm looking for a way to align it differently when it's near the bottom of the container.

Basically, the bottom 2 rows in the container will force the menu off the bottom of the screen, making the user scroll down. Not a massive deal, but I'm sure there should be some way to fix that. At the moment, I simply have position relative (this is in a Django template, though don't really think that's too relevant either). Oh, and I'm using tailwindcss (hence the use of relative  and the other classes there, but a non-tailwind solution would be great ... I can work out later if I can do it with tw stuff or not :slightly_smiling_face: )

```
<div 
    class="relative w-2 mx-1"
    x-data="{ open: false, color: false }" 
    @keydown.escape="open = false" 
    @click.away="open = false"
```

##### Image 1: Kebab menu

[image: Kebab menu]

##### Image 2: Clicked on kebab menu near the top of the container

[image: Kebab menu aligned at the top, near the top of the container (i.e. full menu)]

##### Image 3: Clicked on kebab menu at the end of the container

[image: Kebab menu when near bottom of container (scrolls off bottom ...)]

##### Image 4: Same as image 3, but after I've then scrolled down to see the rest.

[image: Kebab menu near bottom of container after scroll down]